# Is it possible to set a tool as optional within ArcGIS Model Builder?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I have a model with two output files - one is useful always and the other only under certain circumstances. The first (always wanted) is a raster dataset, the other (optional) is a vector feature layer derived from the raster.

**Is it possible to make the last step (including the corresponding tool) optional**, or do I have to make two separate models, one with and one without the final step?

EDIT: I use ArcGIS 10.1.

The output feature layer can help, but it's hard to interpret, so I usually hid it just after creation. It was originally intended as a first step of subsequent model and it will be moved to it, but there are some problems in the next model's creation. Having this layer for each set of parameters is quite handy for me to work on the subsequent model, but almost useless for other users.

Plus, there's curiosity behind that - quite a lot of tools have optional outputs, so even if I didn't need it I'd be curious whether it's possible in model builder too.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?

Comment: Who, or what, determines if the derived vector feature layer is useful?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The purpose of my comment was to determine if the user should be prompted, e.g. "create vector layer? y/n" or if statistics (or other raster analysis) could be used to determine if the vector should be created, e.g. "create vector if histogram has more than 10 values with counts greater than 50". Either way, an if/then branch would be created in the model, but one method requires user input while the other is "automatic".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would if/then logic be an option to split your model in the final part? 
If yes, take a look at: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w00000022000000

Comment: +1 because this is what I think should be tried first.  However, it may be easier to handle within ModelBuilder using more Python and less ModelBuilder